# Prefix unsigned char pointer array with two 0x00 bytes

Tags: c, string, byte, strcat

If for example I have an `unsigned char *str` with the values `0x68 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F`, how can I prefix this array with two null bytes so the array would become `[0x00 0x00] 0x68 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F` (`[]` = added bytes)?

I have tried with `strcat` but this doesn't produce the desired result, I imagine because `0x00` bytes are treated as string terminators.

Comment: unsigned char *str is not an array declaration.

Comment: `strcat` is only intended for strings, i.e. zero-terminated character arrays. Since your array is not zero-terminated, you should not use it.

Comment: Please choose a language: `C` or `c++` but best not to have both, as they are *very* different languages.

Comment: @AdrianMole Understood, I have chosen C

Comment: The values 0x68 etc. are stored in some other part of memory (not in `str`), and `str` tells you where that other memory is  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strcat` is intended for handling strings, i.e. zero-terminated character arrays. Since your array is not zero-terminated, you should not use this function.

Instead, you can use the `memmove` and `memset` functions, if you want to avoid hand-coding the movement. However, you need to declare the `str` array with an **appropriate (larger) size** (to accomodate the added bytes).
So, for example:

```cpp
unsigned char str[7] = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, }; // Note: size must be at least 7
//.. some code
memmove(str+2, str, 5); // Shift along by two bytes (see note, below)
memset(str, 0, 2);      // Add the two 'prefix' zeros
```

Note that the `memmove` function is [safe with overlapping buffers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) (bolding mine):

> Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed by source to
>   the memory block pointed by destination.
>  **Copying takes place as
>   if an intermediate buffer were used, allowing the destination and
>   source to overlap.**

However, this only applies to the function `memmove`, not the function `memcpy`. With the function `memcpy`, it is not safe to have overlapping buffers.

Also, please note that `unsigned char *str` does not declare an array (though you can use similar syntax for [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)). You need to use the (now corrected) version of the posted code.

Comment: Can you please not code-format C and c++? It's uneasy on the eyes and doesn't make a big difference in translation. If you want to specify that they're tags, you can use `[tag:c]` and `[tag:c++]`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Point taken! I'll remember that for future use.